# How to configure alarms snoozing?

Tags: alarms

I would like to have morning alarm which plays a sound for a minute, goes to snooze mode by itself, and repeats everything after 10 minutes.

Is that possible?

Comment: The native alarm app cannot do this but there a ton of other apps. Have you taken a look at any of [these](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-ca/store/search?q=alarm)?

Comment: @karancan I have, and they are are also having issues like app must be open for phone to ring, there are ads and so on.

Comment: general alarm issues http://discussions.nokia.com/t5/Nokia-Lumia/Lumia-925-snooze-issue-Alarm-fail/m-p/2243991/highlight/true#M77708

Answer (score 2):

If you have Windows Phone 8.1 Developer's Preview installed then the recent Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1 will allow you to configure snoozing.

*[Source](http://www.wpcentral.com/snooze-windows-phone)*

Comment: Unfortunately no auto snooze option.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this using the built-in Alarms app and developers do not have access to do stuff like this either with third-party app. It is a limitation set by Microsoft.